# Vue router issue iwth nivagaiotn

Tags: ruby

I already tried and have failed with vue router. I need some help.

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++_)
```

I need help linking vue router to my main component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question. Why do you have a for loop in java syntax in a question related to vue router? Also, this shouldn't be tagged under ruby. For more info on vue router, go to https://router.vuejs.org/.